# Необходимо получить дату из цифр в python

Tags: python, datetime, время

У меня есть ответ о создании реквизитов для платежа, в котором есть также дата создания реквизитов для самого платежа, там расположен текст `1630832322099`, мне необходимо получить год, месяц, день и время с этого текста. Строка `1630832322099` в base64, когда я попытался раскодировать у меня ничего не получилось.

Comment: 1630832322099 - где год, месяц, день и время?

Comment: Я без понятия, написав в поддержку мне написали, что это результат с base64, но у меня не получается раскодировать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1630832322099 это время яваскрипт, милисекунды с начала эпохи. В питоне время в секундах - значит поделить на 1000.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(int('1630832322099')/1000).strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20210905'
```

можно отформатировать в строку, или покомпонентно

```
>>> date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int('1630832322099')/1000)
>>> date.hour
11
>>> date.year
2021
```

также если добавить `%H:%M:%S` в `datetime.fromtimestamp(int('1630832322099')/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`
можно получить час, минуты и секунды